Dynatrace RUM implementation on React app
React app is hosted as a static app with Azure Front door and CDN,
I am planning to do Manual insertion, so i took JavaScript tag from Dynatrace UI and added it to the index.html in React app.
Scripts are downloaded from the CDN,
In Network tab I see there are POST request initiate by those scripts fails with 404,
I am completely new to this Dynatrace, any Idea, did i miss something.
Note:
Post request URL in network tab is http:///rb_xxxxxxxxxx?.....someQueryString
How to config the report URL, also how to get that URL form Dynatrace UI

Have found the way,
since one agent is not installed when application is hosted,
you have to configure the beacon URL, once the URL is configured, adding JS Tag in html does the job
